# How can I update a MySQL date field to be 30 days before another date field?

Tags: mysql, date

I have a column full of order dates in one of my tables, I'd like to populate a new date column with the original order date, minus 30 days.

What's the best syntax to use in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

You could do below:

```
UPDATE your_table SET new_column = order_date - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

or

```
UPDATE your_table SET new_column = DATE_SUB(order_date, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: The first line is working well. What if I want to set the date to +1 year - 30 days?

Comment: Got it: SET RenewalDate = OrderDate + INTERVAL 1 YEAR - INTERVAL 30 DAY

Comment: Do you mean `1 month` by saying `30 day`? If yes, then, better use `1 month`.

Answer (score 0):

Use that column

```
DATE_SUB(colName, INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```